# Xperia M4 Aqua reboot-bootloader only shuts it down

Tags: adb, bootloader

I'm trying to reboot my Xperia M4 Aqua into bootloader mode but all it does it turn it off and I get the battery charging image as if the phone is shut down and in charge.

I tried using the commands

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

and

```
fastboot reboot-bootloader
```

and I also tried doing it manually by pressing volume up button while inserting the usb cable in... same results.

The command

```
adb devices
```

returns the device while

```
fastboot devices
```

doesn't

OS is Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for enlighting me; I always use without hyphen

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

which is in line with [syntax](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html), but for curiosity tried couple of moments ago on Moto G4 with hyphen successfully

```
adb reboot-bootloader
```

But, in what mode you issued command

```
fastboot reboot-bootloader
```

Because you are using Windows platform, [acquire appropriate drivers for that device](https://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/xperia-m4-aqua-driver/).

In developer options, both Enable OEM unlock && USB debugging must be enabled.

Regarding your problem, I briefly looked for same or similar, excluding Samsung and found

[LGV20](https://www.reddit.com/r/lgv20/comments/7660w6/cant_reboot_to_bootloader/), [Wayteq xTab100qcr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42728150/adb-reboot-bootloader-turns-device-off) and [Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19360130/adb-reboot-bootloader-shutdown-my-glass-but-not-reboot).

I'm quite interested in this issue, though never worked with Sony, so specifics of their devices are unknown to me.

Try with [volume-](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/sony/sony-xperia-m4-aqua-e2303/fastboot-mode/) or [volume+](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTKl3pHpftw) button combinations for entering fastboot mode.

If that doesn't help, [look at this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLsn5Zs3nVA).

I remembered I actually had contact with Sony device - it had some sort of custom FRP - my Xperia Theft Protection (MXTP) - but haven't worked with it. I planned to use [Xperia FlashTool](http://www.flashtool.net/index.php).

From Xperia FlashTool you should be able to reboot to bootloader.

Please, do inform what you have done.

Comment: Both commands are accepted, I've read it somewhere.

When I issue the command my phone is on debugging mode and OEM is unlocked. Adb drivers gives back the device but fastboot doesn't. 

When I use adb reboot bootloader it just shuts down, it doesn't turn back on. when I do fastboot reboot bootloader it doesn't find the device.

Comment: I tried both commands and the results were the exact same that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I tried volume- or volume- with no success. Unfortunately my phone cannot be opened without the proper tools so I'm not able to use the video solution

Comment: Just a little update, my phone has gone in bootloop since and sometimes it stops. If for any reason I shut it down the bootloop restarts and I have to wait 5-60 minutes for it to stabilize again. Once stabilized I can't use the wifi and if for some reason I'm able to, it restarts again in bootloop. I'll have to change phone soon because my data can't handle it on its own.